# Flutter proper way to test dart:ui on Android device

Tags: flutter, dart, integration-testing, flutter-test

I faced following problem:

My Android Flutter app has a serie of `dart:ui` calls, basically to do an application files backup. Lets just check how to test that it find the correct path of the app files. **The function to test**:

```dart
  static Future<String> getUserPath() async {
    final appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final pathComponents = path.split(appDocDir.path);
    pathComponents.removeLast();
    final filepaths = path.join(path.joinAll(pathComponents), 'files', '.user');
    if (!await Directory(filepaths).exists()) throw FileSystemException('User directory not found');
    return filepaths;
  }
```

Easy, it call different `dart:ui` functions to check where the user files are. It works now, but I want to write the test for this funcion. Basically I found two ways to test this is: using `Flutter Drive tests` to write integration tests, i followed this tutorial: https://flutter-website-staging.firebaseapp.com/testing/ . And using `Flutter integration tests`, using this guide: https://docs.flutter.dev/testing/integration-tests.

The test I wrote is next:

```dart
    testWidgets('test_correct_path', (WidgetTester tester) async {
      print('user folder: ' + await getUserPath());
      assert('.user' == basename(await getUserPath()));
    });
```

### Using driver tests

- I created the following folder on my project:

```
test_driver
├── backup.dart
└── backup_test.dart
```

- On `backup.dart`

```dart
// This line imports the extension
import 'package:flutter_driver/driver_extension.dart';
import 'package:elRepoIo/main.dart' as app;
void main() {
  // This line enables the extension
  enableFlutterDriverExtension();
}
```

- And on backup_test.dart I just added the needed functions after test `main` declaration:

```dart
void main() {
 FlutterDriver driver;

  // connect flutter driver to the app before executing the runs
  setUpAll(() async {
    driver = await FlutterDriver.connect();
  });

  // disconnect flutter driver from the app after executing the runs
  tearDownAll(() async {
    if (driver != null) {
      driver.close();
    }
  });

  // Tests down here
```

- Then when I execute the tests using `flutter drive --target=test_driver/backup.dart` I receive a bunch of errors such `flutter/packages/flutter_test/lib/src/frame_timing_summarizer.dart:5:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui' import 'dart:ui';`

### Using integration tests

Under

```
integration_test
├── backup_test.dart
```

I wrote the tests adding the following line:

```dart
void main() {
  IntegrationTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized(); // NEW
```

Then I run the test using `flutter test integration_test/backup_test.dart -d $device_id` where I get `device_id` using `flutter devices`.

If I debug this I found that the path is correct, but `await Directory(filepaths).exists()` is `false`.

It seem that if **I run the app to create the folder** and inmetially **I run the tests** the directory exist. Are integration tests deleting all file data? And how can I keep it?